# How to retrieve TimezoneInfo from DateTime object and GPS coordinates

Tags: c#

Can I retrieve (without an internet connection) the correct TimeZoneInfo if I know only my DateTime and the GPS coordinates of my position?

Answer (score 0):

You will need some thrid-party geolocation library to look up

Answer (score 0):

A DateTime pulled from the device OS (or via system clock) won't be of much use, regardless of whether it is set local time or to GMT, if you plan to support users moving the device between timezones.

So, to use the GPS coordinates see this thread for suggestions: [algorithm for getting time zone from geo coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855393/algorithm-for-getting-time-zone-from-geo-coordinates).